# VBScript Dictionary using variables for in/out

Tags: dictionary, vbscript

As a rank amateur I am trying to cobble together a VBScript that contains the following concept:
Using objDictionary with approx. 130 key/item pairs I wish to (output/retrieve and place into a variable) the item value corresponding to the entry of the key value from another variable. Other sites / books do not seem to handle the basics of inputting and outputting except to HTML pages etc. (not of use to me).

Answer (score 1):

Using a variable (sKey) to read/write a value from/to a dictionary:

```
>> Set dicX = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> dicX("one") = 1
>> sKey = "one"
>> nVal = dicX(sKey)
>> WScript.Echo sKey, nVal
>>
one 1
>> dicX(sKey) = 11
>> nVal = dicX(sKey)
>> WScript.Echo sKey, nVal
>>
one 11
```